# Premixed ingredients for yogurt

Tags: yogurt

I failed to read the recipe before I started to make my first batch of yogurt.  I poured the whole milk and mixed in the premade yogurt.  Can I still boil till 200 degrees, then let cool and then add another 1/2 cup of premade?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. I would certainly say that it's worth a try, because there is a high chance it will work. Of course, you do need to add more culture after cooling, but you already mentioned this in the question.

If this fails, the most likely failure mode will be that the acid in the culturing yogurt is sufficient, and your milk old enough, that it curdles when heated together. This means that you can either throw it away now, or give it a cook and see if it stays liquid, and if yes, continuing as usual. If it curdles, you can use it as quark. So continuing instead of dumping it is the winning strategy, your worst possible loss is a bit of electricity.

Comment: Thank You!  I did try this and it worked.  Glad I took the time to try it.